# Unable to use the output of inputdlg in the get function

Tags: matlab, handles

I want to use the input value from the dialog box and save it as sp_name. Saving it directly to sp_name is giving me an error. Kindly help me out. It seems that as soon as the inputdlg is closed, ans variable is destroyed. what should I do?

**Code:**

```
ans = inputdlg('Save as:','New user');
sp_name=get(handles.ans,'String');
```

**Error:**

```
 Reference to non-existent field 'ans'
```

Comment: I have edited the post. Kindly let me know if you get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from inputdlg is a cell array. Hence you need to use:

```
sp_name = ans{1};
```

In your code above, Matlab does not recognize the structure handles and it throws the error.